# How to Data Bind Dynamically Generated Columns with Key-Valued Pairs?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm building a wpf application with the MVVM framework. I have a set of data that is repetitive and am trying to figure out a way to consolidate the set. The dataset is designed for each employee assigned to a job to log their days worked per month. The approach they used in the database was to have a startdate & enddate with a correlating number of days worked. The problem with this is that I receive multiple tuples per resource. I've developed my datagrid to dynamically generate month columns based on the startdates depending on the project that was selected. I would like to take the value of daysworked per month per resource and assign it to the column that is labelled with said month. Here is an image for reference:
[image]
I understand the logic in that "select DaysWorked where resourceId == resourceID && StartDate == StartDate" but I cannot find any resources that can help me in how to bind this relationship to the columns that don't exist in xaml and are generated during runtime. Here is my code for generating the columns

```
private void ResourceGrid_Headers(MainViewModel mvm)
    {
        string format = "MMMM yyyy";
        List<SchedulesModel> allDates = mvm.ScheduleVM._Schedules.ToList();
        List<SchedulesModel> dates = allDates.DistinctBy(x => x.StartDate).ToList();
        int count = dates.Count() - 1;
        DateTime start = dates[0].StartDate.GetValueOrDefault();
        DateTime end = dates[count].EndDate.GetValueOrDefault();
        List<String> dateArray = new List<string>();

        dates.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate);

        foreach(var item in dates)
        {
            dateArray.Add(item.StartDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(format));
        }
        
        foreach(var item in mvm.ScheduleVM._Schedules)
        {
            //??
        }
        //add array to columns
        for (int i = 0; i < dateArray.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn c = new DataGridTextColumn();
            System.Windows.Data.Binding b = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(mvm.ScheduleVM._Schedules.
                Select(x => x.DaysPerMonth).ToString());
            c.Binding = b;
            c.Header = dateArray[i];
            resourceGrid.Columns.Add(c);
        }
        
    }
```

and the xaml for the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="resourceGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ScheduleVM._Schedules}" BorderBrush="#FF4480A8" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Padding="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Resource" DisplayMemberPath="ResourceName" SelectedValuePath="ResourceID" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ResourceID}">
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ResourcesVM._Resources, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ResourcesVM._Resources, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Role" DisplayMemberPath="RoleName" SelectedValuePath="RoleID" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding RoleID}">
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.RolesVM._Roles, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.RolesVM._Roles, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project Days" Binding="{Binding DaysPerMonth}"/>
```

I would also like to mention that I'm not sure what kind of collection to use with 2 parameters. I would like to stick with ObservableCollection but I doubt that's possible as the Month columns are not in any model. As far as I know Dictionary only takes 1 key. So my question is:

How would I bind each column to a value based off of resourceid and startdate?

Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: any reason you cannot convert it to a more usable model for display? Convert your current model (one that is used to read from the data source) to a model that satisfies your display needs. Put that logic elsewhere and not in the viewmodel. And if you are planning to make changes at the view, then I would definitely use ObservableCollection & INotifyPropertyChanged. Rather my opinion is to use it anyway, as I have always noticed - once the first app is developed (which helps the users/business), further developments to improve user interactivity are always made.

Comment: The reason I cannot set up a model for it, is that the month columns are going to change depending on the project that is loaded. So there is no way for me to set the properties for every  possible month.

Comment: ah, i see. can you add your current xaml binding code (the bottom datagrid part) to the question.

Comment: yeah, sure; one moment.